# One that is holding a conversation

Tags: single-word-requests, nouns

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Shorter way to say “conversational partner”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29388/shorter-way-to-say-conversational-partner)

What's a good word for something or someone who is holding a conversation? Or perhaps a bit broader, someone who knows how to hold a conversation with someone or something.

Need a name for something or someone who knows how to hold a conversation with something or someone.

Was thinking Conversationist, but that doesn't seem to be a word :p

Comment: _[Conversationalist](http://www.wordnik.com/words/conversationalist)_?

Comment: raconteur, if you are not looking to contribute much to the conversation :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

One who is *good* at making conversation is a [conversationalist](http://i.word.com/idictionary/Conversationalist).

Comment: I agree that conversationalist is probably the right answer (I think OP's phrase "knows how to" implies that the person is good at making conversation). You could also call such a person a good communicator, though the meaning is broader.

Comment: a **sparkling** conversationalist, if you don't mind a cliché

Comment: Ah, so I wasn't too far off then. Was just missing an 'al'. Think I'll go for this!

Answer (score 6):

The standard term is [interlocutor](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&newwindow=1&q=interlocutor&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=NJV8Tui_CaSa0QWG2bwK&sqi=2&ved=0CBsQkQ4&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=dea43aca69e1ef5a&biw=1427&bih=920), but if the word *conversation* (or an equivalent) is already in the context, people often prefer the less "wordy" term [participant](http://www.google.co.uk/#sclient=psy-ab&hl=en&newwindow=1&tbs=dfn:1&source=hp&q=participant&pbx=1&oq=participant&aq=f&aqi=g10&aql=1&gs_sm=e&gs_upl=112438l114922l9l115610l11l10l0l1l1l0l156l1076l2.7l9l0&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.&fp=cb1998aa30ea7126&biw=1427&bih=920).

As @Simchona says, there is also *conversationalist*, but ordinarily this specifically means someone who is *habitually good at keeping up the flow* of conversation, so that other participants feel interested/relaxed/motivated and will thus also actively participate. It doesn't normally mean someone who talks a lot it such a way that others listen without saying much themselves, nor does it mean someone who happens to be in a conversation right now.

Comment: Think I'll go with conversationalist, as it in my context it isn't necessarily in a conversation *right now*. Knows how to and could be. Also, I don't think anyone would understand what I was talking about if I used the word interlocutor :D

Comment: @Svish: There's no doubt *conversationalist* is the right word for one who's *good* at it, but *interlocutor* isn't exactly rare. In fact it's become the [more common word](http://ngrams.googlelabs.com/graph?content=conversationalist%2Cinterlocutor&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) over recent decades, so I wouldn't worry about people not understanding.

Answer (score 2):

A neutral word would be *converser*, though it's not too common.

Answer (score 0):

I have seen *conversant* used for this kind of thing.