# What are "people in a conversation" called in English?

Tags: single-word-requests

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [One that is holding a conversation](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/43034/one-that-is-holding-a-conversation)

Currently I am trying to develop a **mail software** and I want to find the right word (if it exists) for people who are in a conversation. It is not *contact list* or *mail list*. It should be a word for the people.

So, what is it called in English? Is there any word for these people?

Comment: You should note that we don't speak of *"**a** [mail] software"* in English. See this earlier question [Why don't we use the indefinite article with 'software'?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/12990/)

Comment: Umm, this question is NOT a duplicate of the cited question. The title of that question is misleading. If you read the text of the question, that person is asking for a word meaning someone who is good at conversation, i.e. a conversationalist. This question is asking for someone who is participating in a particular conversation.

Comment: This question brings to mind a general comment on single-word requests: It is not uncommon for such requests to elicit words that meet the definition but that are not commonly used. In many cases, I would prefer to use a word that is vague or broad or "close but not quite" but that my readers are likely to understand rather than an "exact match" that few will have ever heard before, especially if context will make the meaning of the "close but not quite" reasonably clear. Obviously there are judgement calls here.

Comment: This question should not be reopened. StackExchange prefers to discourage single word requests unless they are quite interesting. And this is, in fact, a duplicate of the older question. The body of the older question agrees with the title: "What's a good word for something or someone who is holding a conversation? Or perhaps a bit broader, someone who knows how to hold a conversation with someone or something." I don't know how Jay jumped to someone who is "good at" conversation.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Per existing answers, in practice, *participants* may be the best fit for OP's exact context.

But more generally, [a conversation consists of **conversants**, language exchanged between the agents, agreements reached by the agents, and a memory that keeps track of all the agreements](http://books.google.co.uk/books?id=7bl9-Qn8LwQC&pg=PA98&dq=%22conversants%22&hl=en&sa=X&ei=N2KRUNLuIqPT0QXM74DYCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBQ#v=onepage&q=%22conversants%22&f=false).

Answer (score 7):

I'd suggest one of:

- Participants
- Speakers
- Conversers
- [Dialogists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dialogist)
- [Interlocutors](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/interlocutor) (technically not entirely accurate; see [locutors](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interlocutor_%28linguistics%29))

I must say that I have never heard of *dialogists* before today. But it fits the bill.

Comment: A *conversationalist* is someone who is good at conversation and *dialogist* I've never heard of either. I would not use either of those words here.

Comment: @z7sgѪ Going by the dictionary definition, apparently _conversationalist_ also applies to those who participate in conversations. But, I agree that _-ist_ suggests expert/professional.

Comment: Participants: good. Could refer to people participating in something other than a conversation, like "participants in the ball game", but works given proper context. Speakers: means people making formal presentations at a conference or meeting, not people who are talking in general. Conversers: not a commonly-used word. I just looked it up and its in the dictionary but its meaning was not quite clear to me. Conversationalists: means people who are good at conversation in general, not participating in one particular conversation. ...

Comment: Dialogist: Not a common word. I think it refers more to people speaking in a play or movie than general conversation. Interlocutor: I think this refers more to someone speaking in an official capacity, like the interlocutors in a court case.

Comment: @Jay Their dictionary definitions all fits the OP's requirements. I've added them in due to the fact that _participants_ does not explicitly indicate people involved in conversation; it's a general term. I think that _conversant_ is another word that fits into this category; I would not equate it with a person taking part in a conversation.

Comment: Well that is wiktionary and in my opinion that definition is poor.  The example usage for meaning 1 is clearly an example of meaning 2.  I can't see meaning 1 in any reference dictionaries.  I think it's just wrong.

Comment: @z7sgѪ hmm, you're right. Nuking now. Thank you.

Comment: @z7sgѪ so what is your advice?

Comment: @dinobeytar Seems to me that participants is a good choice.

Answer (score 3):

I would probably call them "Participants". I don't think there's any specific word used exclusively by e-mail software.

Answer (score 3):

*Recipients* could work for a mailing program.