# "conversation-partner" and "conversation-mate"

Tags: word-choice

Is it appropriate to say that the person I'm having a conversation with is my
**conversation-partner**, or do I have to say [conversational partner](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29388/shorter-way-to-say-conversational-partner)? And if **"conversation-partner"** is Ok, what about **conversation-mate**?

I will give a concrete situation: Let's say I have a radio program, and I say: "Today we are going to talk about Physics. My **conversation-mate** is John Doe". So in this situation, which expression is better?

Last note: This question is not a duplicate. There is no question about "converation-mate". Also, I don't want to use less common words like "[interlocutor](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29388/shorter-way-to-say-conversational-partner)" or "[conversant](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/89715/what-are-people-in-a-conversation-called-in-english)".

Comment: If you're hosting a radio program the people you bring on are usually called your 'guests'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Let's say I have a radio program, and I say: 'Today we are going to talk about Physics. My conversation-mate is John Doe'" is acceptable usage, as is "conversation partner" or simply "guest," as suggested by StoneyB. Go with what feels natural to you.